# Confirmation of Proof: For some $v\in\mathbb{Z}$, $12v^2 - 4v + 3$ is never a square.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation, roots, irrational-numbers

I am trying to prove that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. I can use modulo, and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (FTOA), but I decided to approach it a little bit differently this time: I decided to use some quadratics.

It is quite long, but it is unfinished, as there is this one part I need to prove:

> That for some $v\in\mathbb{Z}$, namely the set of all integers, $12v^2 - 4v + 3$ is never a square.

I have no idea how to approach this. What are some useful skills or knowledge I should know about square numbers or similar (quadratic) problems? I would really appreciate a hint, but full answers are acceptable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$12v^2-4v+3\equiv-1\pmod4$$

But for any integer $a,$ $$a^2\equiv0,1\pmod4$$

Comment: Why is this the case? Is this a well-known theorem?

Comment: @user477343 If $a$ is even then $a=2n$ and $a^2=4n^2=0 \mod 4$. If $a$ is odd then $a=2n+1$ and $a^2=4n^2+4n+1=1 \mod 4$.

Comment: @gandalf61 thank you for telling me. I quite figured that out anyway, but if it was not for your comment, I would have forgotten to tick this answer, haha.

Comment: Very good answer. If you explained just a little bit more, it would have been ideal. Congratulations, nonetheless! $$(+1) \ \ \color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: @user477343, Sorry for being late. Hope you have understood the method now.

Comment: No problemo :) ${}$

Answer (score 2):

$$
12v^2-4v+3=n^2\Rightarrow v = \frac{1}{24}\left(4\pm\sqrt{16-16 \times 3(3-n^2)}\right)
$$

but

$$
1-3(3-n^2) \ge 0\Rightarrow n^2 \le \frac{8}{3}\Rightarrow n^2\le 2\Rightarrow n \in \{0, \pm 1\}
$$

Comment: I like your approach, and in using the quadratic formula, we see that values $n=0$ and $n=\pm 1$ do not yield $v\in\mathbb{Z}$, proving that there are no integer solutions. However, I am not too familiar with inequalities (and I think it should be $n\in\{0,\pm 1\}$ as opposed to $n=\{0,\pm 1\}$) so that is why I did not tick this answer. But thank you anyway for stretching out my perspective :) $$(+1)$$

Comment: Your notation is more exact an I will change it. Thanks.

Comment: No problemo :) ${}$